# Is there a method to set the width of a div to its height in CSS?

Tags: css

In CSS, if I want to set a div's height to its width, I can use `padding-bottom:100%`. However, I want to set a certain div's height to the viewport height, and have the div's width resize so that the div is square. Is there a method of doing so in CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aim to set its height to the viewport height, you can as well set its width to the viewport height:

```
.square {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}
```

*In case you're not familiar with this unit: `1vh` represents one percent of the view height.*

**Edit:** depending on how responsive you want your design to be, you can also make use of the `1vmin` unit, which represents 1 percent of the smallest side of your screen.

```
.square {
  height: 100vmin;
  width: 100vmin;
}
```

Regardless of whether your website is viewed in portrait or landscape mode, the square will always max out its size without causing the page to scroll.

Comment: I will accept the answer once it allows me to.

Comment: That's fine. I've updated my answer to introduce another approach that might even have more benefits.

Comment: This new approach is even better! Thank you very much!